# Please color links on meta

Tags: petición-de-funcionalidad

I have seen the links are black in the meta site and they are just underlined. Please make them colored like other per-site metas on SE. A link should be different than the rest of the words so that it's obvious they are links (and just to be underlined doesn't necessary mean the word(s) are links).

Other problem is that with black links it's very hard to differentiate removed accounts from active ones in comments and OP cards when the username is `user*****` (* is a number). We have to click on all of them in order to find if they are active or not.

The other problem is when we want to put images in our questions. With black links the "Browse" and "paste" options are like plain text (they aren't underlined in any sites). Of course, we are still able to post our images, but I think it would be more beautiful to have colored links here.

The reason for this black link thing is the colored tag cards. The tag cards should be black just like other per-site metas so that the links are orange/brown like them.

Comment: As I think you know this is not specific to this site and belongs on the Meta site where you have indeed made a feature request.

Comment: @mdewey I have posted a separate question on Meta SE too.